# Jacobian for Conversion Between Polar and Cartesian Resembles a Rotation Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus

In matrix form, supposing $z=f(x,y)$ where x,y represent the cartesian coordinate system, one can write the chain rule:

$ \begin{bmatrix}
z_x \\
z_y 
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
r_x & \theta_x \\
r_y & \theta_y 
\end{bmatrix}   
 \begin{bmatrix}
z_r \\
z_\theta 
\end{bmatrix}$

Which turns out to be

$ \begin{bmatrix}
z_x \\
z_y 
\end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix}
\cos\theta & -\frac{\sin\theta}{r} \\
\sin\theta & \frac{\cos\theta}{r} 
\end{bmatrix}  
 \begin{bmatrix}
z_r \\
z_\theta 
\end{bmatrix}$

Why does this middle matrix resemble a rotation and a scaling by 1/r so much?

Comment: Did my answer explain your question or smth nnot clear? If not, could you explain what it is so I can modify the answer. Thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/PlanetPhysics/Transformation_Between_Cartesian_Basis_Vectors_and_Polar_Basis_Vectors have a look at the btotom most part of the site

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the Jacobian represents the best linear approximation or differential $dF$ of the change of coordinates map $F(r,\theta) = r(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ that stretches a rectangle in the $(r,\theta)$ plane to a "polar rectangle" in the $(x,y)$ plane. (Screenshot below shows a relevant drawing I made when teaching Calc 3 online.)

[image]

If you remember that the columns of the matrix tell you where the original basis vectors (in this case, the canonical basis in the $(r,\theta)$ plane) get mapped to, then it is simple to understand geometrically why the the first column vector points radially outwards, and why the second column vector is rotated 90 degrees and also stretched by the radial factor (points further away from the origin in the $(x,y)$ plane must rotate faster as you move vertically in the $(r,\theta)$ plane, since the rectangles get bigger).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this seems like an excellent answer! I have some confusions about j vector having length r in the x-y plane, which I think the other answer attempts to explain. Once I get this, I will accept both answers. Thanks

Comment: @SanjitRaman If it helps, picture the original $\vec j$ as the tangent vector of a vertical unit-speed curve $\vec r(t) = t \vec j$ starting at the point $(r,\theta)$ and ending at $(r,\theta+2\pi)$, then in exactly $2\pi$ units of time the corresponding curve $\vec F \circ \vec r$ in the xy plane traces out at constant speed a full circle starting and ending at the same point $(x,y) = (r\cos \theta, r \sin\theta)$. But this curve can be parametrized as $\vec s(t) = r(\cos(\theta +t), \sin(\theta + t))$, and $d\vec F(\vec j) = \vec s\ '(0) = r(-\sin \theta, \cos \theta)$, which has length $r$.

Answer (score 3):

Because that is what it is in a way.  The action of a rotation matrix is specified by the action of it on basis vectors. Under rotation of a given angle, e_x gets sent to r hat of that angle and e_y to theta hat of that angle.

Comment: The r factor comes for scaling down the e_theta vector. Naturally e_theta has a length of r. When I said theta hat, I mean e_ theta divided by r

Comment: Why does e-theta have a length r in the x-y plane?

Comment: Due to definition, some books put it as length one and some other as length 'r'. If you want a deeper reason on WHY they choose that definition, that's a bit complicated... but for now just keep in mind it's definition